# Limiting number of items in a GridView C# UWP

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I use a grid view which is binded to a collection. The collection is holding an unknown number of items and I want to limit the GridView to show only 5 items in one row. Each item is hold inside a stackpanel which holds a text block and an image.

A. How can I limit the GridView num of items?
B. If I don't want to limit it how can I make a gridview of 1 row which with a little arrow scroll the grid to the side?

Here is my xaml code:

```
 <GridView Name="ListViewGrid" Background="Azure" 
              Grid.Row="2" 
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ForeCasts}" 
              Foreground="Chartreuse" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ForeCast">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20,20,20,20" Height="260" Width="260">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                        <Run Text="{x:Bind TempString}" FontSize="24" Foreground="Black"/>
                        <Run Text="&#x00B0;" FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontSize="24"/>
                        <Run Text="C" FontSize="24"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind ImageString}" Width="60" Height="60"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The collection is holding an unknown number of items and I want to limit the GridView to show only 5 items in one row.

[**GridView**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx) uses [**ItemsWrapGrid**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.aspx) as the default [**ItemsPanel**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx). And [**ItemsWrapGrid**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.aspx) has a [**MaximumRowsOrColumns** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.maximumrowsorcolumns.aspx). With this property we can limit the maximum rows or columns that will present before wrapping. This property works with [**Orientation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.orientation.aspx) property. To show only 5 items in one row, we can set it like following:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="5" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Please note that `MaximumRowsOrColumns` only limits the maximum number, if the `GridView` is not large enough, you might see less items.

> If I don't want to limit it how can I make a gridview of 1 row which with a little arrow scroll the grid to the side?

To display a collection stacked horizontally, we usually use a [**ListView**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx). If you do want to use `GridView`, you can using [**ItemsStackPanel**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemsstackpanel.aspx) instead of `ItemsWrapGrid` like following:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

To enable scrolling, you might also need to set [**ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility.aspx) property and [**ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollmode.aspx) property like following:

```
<GridView Name="ListViewGrid"
          Grid.Row="2"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="Azure"
          Foreground="Chartreuse"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind ForeCasts}"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ForeCast">
            <StackPanel Width="260"
                        Height="260"
                        Margin="20,20,20,20"
                        Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run FontSize="24" Foreground="Black" Text="{x:Bind TempString}" />
                    <Run FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontSize="24" Text="&#x00B0;" />
                    <Run FontSize="24" Text="C" />
                </TextBlock>
                <Image Width="60" Height="60" Source="{x:Bind ImageString}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Hello Jay, say for example I use ItemsWrap GridMaximumRowsOrColumns="3" and I have totally 18 items that are shown by 6 rows. But, I want to show only the 1'st row or maybe the 1'st & 2'nd. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @axcelenator If you want to show only the first row, then you may need to change the `ItemsSource`. For example, if you want to show the first three items, you can retrieve them form `ForeCasts` and set the three items as `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. I thought there is some way to limiting that source without changing the original source.