# Items in Gridview doesn't shows vertically with scrolling

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

I want to display number of items vertically one after another with radio button selection option. But my implementation code doesn't shows properly. I've faced two problems here:

1. Grid Items not shows vertically. It shows horizontally after 3 items
2. Scrolling is disabled

Here is my output and expected output:

[image]

Here is my Tried Code:

```
<Grid Width="333"
      CornerRadius="26"
      HighContrastAdjustment="None"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid Margin="24,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="160"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RelativePanel MinHeight="30"
                       Margin="0,15">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectText, Mode=OneWay}"
                FontFamily="Segoe UI Regular"
                FontSize="15"
                FontWeight="SemiBold"/>

            <Button Name="btnClose" Width="28"
                        Height="28"
                        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                        Command="{Binding CancelButton_ClickRelayCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </RelativePanel>

        <GridView x:Name="DayListView" Grid.Row="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Days, Mode=OneWay}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              IsTapEnabled="False">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton Height="19" FontFamily="Segoe UI Regular" FontSize="10" Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" GroupName="Day" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"></RadioButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4" Padding="0">
            <TextBlock Text="+"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontFamily="Segoe UI Regular"
               FontSize="20"
               FontWeight="SemiBold"
               Foreground="#00A53C"/>
            <Button x:Name="AddDayButton"
                IsTabStop="False"
                Padding="0"
                Margin="10,0,0,0"
                Background="Transparent"
                FontSize="12"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                FontFamily="Segoe UI Regular"
                Content="{Binding AddDayText, Mode=OneWay}"
                Command="{Binding AddDayButtonClickRelayCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I want to shows all items vertically with scroll enable. Plz help me

Comment: Have you considered using `ListView` instead of `GridView`? Your expected result reminds me more of a `ListView` which is vertical by default and only shows 1 column of items by default.

Comment: @Batesias, Thanks for your suggestion but I've faced some issue on Listview .Thats why i want to use gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should used `ItemsStackPanel` instead of `WrapGrid`. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40844277/6176507) for more details.

I've used your layout and produced exact same output as you expected. Here is my sample code:

```
<GridView x:Name="DayListView" Grid.Row="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Days, Mode=OneWay}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton Height="19" Width="280" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI Regular" FontSize="10" Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" GroupName="Day" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"></RadioButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Grid Items not shows vertically. It shows horizontally

If you has set `WrapGrid` Orientation="Vertical", it will place the items horizontally and limit fixed row number. derive from your screenshot the row number is 3.

> Scrolling is disabled

If you have set `WrapGrid` Orientation="Vertical", but the default scroll model is vertical, for scenario, you need enable horizontal scroll model manually.

```
<GridView 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
```

**Update**

For getting the expect one, you need set Orientation="Vertical"

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapGrid ItemWidth="80" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

[image]